# fetch data employee table with 1 id and multiple transaction id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, transactions

here in transaction table one employee have multiple  transaction .i want all transaction of 1 specific employee .but employee id should be print once in column .here is format

1.here one employee have more than one transaction id .id should display 1 time and display all transaction

desired result: employee details should display in one row but transaction id in multiple row

error id repeating id:

[image: image of the results]

Copied from comments:

```
select 
  b.TransactionId,
  a.Name
from 
  TransactionRecharge b 
  left JOIN Customer a on a.Id=b.CustomerId 
where 
  b.CustomerId=101282
```

Comment: can you please show your own query that you tried

Comment: select b.TransactionId ,a.Name from TransactionRecharge b 
left  JOIN Customer a on  a.Id=b.CustomerId where b.CustomerId=101282

Comment: select b.TransactionId ,a.Name from TransactionRecharge b 
left  JOIN Customer a on  a.Id=b.CustomerId where b.CustomerId=101282

Comment: HERE IT IS PRINTING NAME MULTIPLE TIME .I WANT NAME SHOULD PRINT ONLY ONE TIME AND ALL TRANSACTION ID SHOULD PRINT

Comment: You should edit your question and stop using all caps letters -- and try to write questions that clear and easy to understand

Comment: Hi James .on executing your query it is giving                                                 20150826155559917 Mitesh Vora
20150826155808350 Mitesh Vora
20150826160328137 Mitesh Vora
20150826162446127 Mitesh Vora
20150826180800720 Mitesh Vora
20150826180930290 Mitesh Vora
20150826181120167 Mitesh Vora
20150826181229560 Mitesh Vora
20150826181246200 Mitesh Vora
20150826181443047 Mitesh Vora
20150826181622530 Mitesh Vora
20150826184440540 Mitesh Vora
20150826184604893 Mitesh Vora
20150826190538497 Mitesh Vora
20150826190904870 Mitesh Vora
20150826200054267 Mitesh Vora

Comment: and i want         Mitesh Vora 20150826114215163
                                          20150826114314010
                                           20150826114551253
                                            20150826114734697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a **Good practice**, I am pretty sure that "*I am going to get negative marks for helping you*", Anyway i just did for what you asked.

> Below Query using [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms186734.aspx) will help you get what you need exactly.

```
CREATE TABLE #customer(Id INT PRIMARY KEY,Name VARCHAR(255))
CREATE TABLE #TransactionRecharge(TransactionId VARCHAR(255),CustomerId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #customer(id))

INSERT INTO #customer
VALUES (1,'Raj'),(2,'Bala'),(3,'Chandra')

INSERT INTO #TransactionRecharge
VALUES ('reansaction1',1),('reansaction2',1),
       ('reansaction3',1),('reansaction4',1),
       ('reansaction5',1),('reansaction6',1),
       ('reansaction7',1),('reansaction8',2)

SELECT  
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.TransactionId,a.Id) = '1' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,a.Id)
        ELSE ''
    END AS Customer,
    CASE
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.TransactionId,a.Id) = '1' THEN Name
        ELSE ''
    END AS Name,
    b.TransactionId  
FROM
    #TransactionRecharge b
LEFT JOIN 
    #customer a ON a.Id = b.CustomerId
WHERE 1 = 1
--AND   b.CustomerId = 1
DROP TABLE #customer
DROP TABLE #TransactionRecharge
```

Comment: hi Ragul .yes there are two table 1 is customer table and second is transaction table.1 customer can have multiple transaction.so i want name should print 1 time and all transaction should print .

Comment: @radhasingh Updated my answer, Please check i.

Comment: Thank you Ragul.its working properly.it is giving result as according my desire

Comment: @radhasingh You are Welcome , Add my answer as solution !